# creating new column values depending on other column values in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series, data-processing

I have a data frame and a snippet of it is given below.

```
data = {'ID':['A', 'A', 'A,'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'Date':['03/25/2021', '03/25/2021',03/27/2021', '03/29/2021', '03/10/2021','03/11/2021','03/15/2021','03/16/2021', '03/21/2021','03/25/2021']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I am looking for a final result which should look like this.

[image]

The explanation: For each ID, the study_date starts from the starting date and ends on the last date. The missing dates in the middle have to be filled. If the date was missing from the original dataframe, then 'missing_date' column will have value 1 or else 0. And the study day column is the number of days from the starting to ending days incrementing in order.

I tried some stuff but I have been stuck on this for a while now. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def fn(x):
    dr = pd.date_range(x["Date"].min(), x["Date"].max())
    out = pd.DataFrame({"Date": dr}, index=range(1, len(dr) + 1))
    out["Missing_Date"] = (~out["Date"].isin(x["Date"])).astype(int)
    return out


# if the "Date" column is not converted:
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

x = (
    df.groupby("ID")
    .apply(fn)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "StudyDay"})
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   ID  StudyDay       Date  Missing_Date
0   A         1 2021-03-25             0
1   A         2 2021-03-26             1
2   A         3 2021-03-27             0
3   A         4 2021-03-28             1
4   A         5 2021-03-29             0
5   B         1 2021-03-10             0
6   B         2 2021-03-11             0
7   B         3 2021-03-12             1
8   B         4 2021-03-13             1
9   B         5 2021-03-14             1
10  B         6 2021-03-15             0
11  B         7 2021-03-16             0
12  C         1 2021-03-21             0
13  C         2 2021-03-22             1
14  C         3 2021-03-23             1
15  C         4 2021-03-24             1
16  C         5 2021-03-25             0
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. A small addition/edit to the question, if there are multiple entries of the same dates, then 'study_day' has to be '1' & '1' as shown in the figure.  The current code removes the repeated entry of dates if there are any.